# How do I read a table without encountering a Value Error from pd.read_html

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

How do I read the table at [https://dune.com/queries/870929] without encountering an error that displays "ValueError: No tables found"?

The code that I use is:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://dune.com/queries/870929"
Dune_Table = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(url).content, "lxml"
)
Table_Finder = Dune_Table.find("table", {"class": "table_table__fuS_N"})
Data_Frame_Convert = pd.read_html(str(Table_Finder).upper())[0]
```

Comment: If you cook a `soup`, you should taste it to be sure that it contains the expected ingredients.